# WPF: Set Control Height to Fill Grid Row Height

Tags: wpf, grid, height

A WPF Grid control with 3 row and 3 columns. The Height of the Row in question is set to Auto. In the first two cells I have two controls with dynamic heights. In the third cell, I have another control I want to be automatically set to stretch within the Grid cell. I have tried `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`, but that simply sets Grid Row Height equal to control's height. What are my options here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what kind of control you are using in Cell 3, but most of the WPF controls will automatically stretch to fit inside the Grid cell.  The row height of your grid will be set by the height of the controls in Cells 1 and 2.

If you are using some kind of custom control where the default behavior for height is different, you can set `Height="Auto"`.

If that doesn't work either, you can do a data binding to get the actual height of the control in either cell 1 or 2.  Set the `Height` property of your control in Cell 3 to the following:

```
Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyControlNameFromCell1, Mode=OneWay}"
```

**EDIT**

Another way that might be more robust is to do a data binding for the Height of the row.  So instead of using `"Auto"` for the height of the row, use the data binding shown above.

Comment: Thanks. The control in cell 3 is a TabControl, whereas Cell 1 and Cell 2 have Grids in them. The problem is that the contents of TabControl (and therefore the TableControl itself) are larger than both Grids, so the entire row takes the height of TabControl. What I want instead is for TabControl to take the height of the Grids (larger one of them) and introduce a scrollbar within itself to expose all its contents. I have already added a ScrollViewer in the TabControl too, but since the TabControl becomes large enough to show all its contents, the ScrollViewer remains useless.

Comment: Update. Binding actually does work. The problem was that I had Margin="3" in TabControl's properties which was somehow causing it to become as large as its contents required. Removing Margin and adding the Height binding you mentioned above seems to do the trick.